# How to insert data using relation?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two table

**posts**

```
id|post_title|post_content
```

**post_images**

```
id|images|post_id
```

**Controller**

```
public function AddPost(Request $request)
    {
        Post::create($request->all());
        // PostImage::create();
        return Redirect::to('Post');
    }
```

Also i have added Relation

```
class Post extends Model
{
protected $table = 'posts';

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\PostImage');
    }
}


class PostImage extends Model
{
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
}
```

I have one form where i adding post title ,post content and selecting multiple images. My question is how I can store post images along with post id in post_images table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your code like this

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'posts';
    //add $fillable here
    protected $fillable = ['post_title', 'post_content'];

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(App\PostImage::class);
    }
}


class PostImage extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'post_images';
    //add $fillable here
    protected $fillable = ['images', 'post_id'];

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Post::class);
    }
}
```

> Now in your controller

```
Post::create($request->all())->images()->create($request->all());
```

> Here **`Post create`** saves your data to db also **`returns the object`** then
>   you accesses the **`relation images`** and saves data to **`images`**.

See here for more details [**`One To Many`**](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: .simply superb.thank you so much.it works fine.suppose if i have multiple image can it insert into multiple row

Comment: i am selecting multiple images from input file

Comment: yes if you have your input as array e.g **`<input name="files[]" />`** it will insert multiple row as well

Comment: hi if i add arrays of images then it will not insert into my image table.means in my view suppose if i have <input name="files[]" /> then wont work.if i have <input name="files" /> then it works